# Unknown Exception? java.nio.file.FileSystemException: Invalid exchange

Tags: java

I'm encountering an error I've never seen before, and can't find any information about.

If I try to walk a (large, 1 million files in several nested sub-directories. Only 1-300 files/folders per directory) file path, I get the following stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /PATH_HERE/: Invalid exchange
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.fetchNextIfNeeded(FileTreeIterator.java:88)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.hasNext(FileTreeIterator.java:104)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:115)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at my.class.NGram.run(NGram.java:90)
    at my.class.NGram.main(NGram.java:81)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /PATH_HERE: Invalid exchange
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.asIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixDirectoryStream$UnixDirectoryIterator.readNextEntry(UnixDirectoryStream.java:171)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixDirectoryStream$UnixDirectoryIterator.hasNext(UnixDirectoryStream.java:201)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.next(FileTreeWalker.java:348)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.fetchNextIfNeeded(FileTreeIterator.java:84)
    ... 10 more
```

The code on line 90 looks like

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<File> queuOfAllFiles = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    FileVisitor<? super Path> fileVisitor = new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>()
    {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
        {
            if (attrs != null && file != null && attrs.isRegularFile())
                queuOfAllFiles.add(file.toFile());
            return super.visitFile(file, attrs);
        }

    };
    Files.walkFileTree(dir.toPath(), EnumSet.of(FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS), Integer.MAX_VALUE, fileVisitor); //This line errors
```

The original code look like this, which produces the same error

```
List<File> allFiles = Files.walk(dir.toPath(), FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)
            .filter(p -> !Files.isReadable(p))
            .map(p -> p.toFile())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I can't seem to find anything about this error anywhere, or what could be causing it. Tools to touch / look at all the files on the system seem to run without problem, such as

```
find /PATH_HERE -type f | wc -l
```

Gives me the correct number of files (about 1 million)

This is running on a system with 40 TB of SSD storage, 64 CPU cores, and 2 TB of RAM running Ubuntu 16.04. Java version info below.

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

I'm looking for any help I can get on what might be causing this or other things to try. I just have no ideas at this point and can't find any info.

Comment: It appears the underlying native code is failing with `errno` equal to `EBADE`;  see https://linux.die.net/man/3/errno .  Unfortunately, I cannot for the life of me find an explanation of what EBADE means.  The closest I was able to find was https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2008-March/msg00012.html .  Is there anything unusual about the file tree or media you’re traversing?

Comment: No, nothing unusual about it. Just lots of files broken up into a sub-directory tree so that we don't have tools break on a *giant* folder.

Comment: I would add .parallel() before .filter() anyway... because you say it's about 1 million files.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have to follow symbolic links? Could be a potential trouble spot.
Also, have you tried walking the tree using your own recursive function? You might be able to locate the specific offending file/directory.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to leave comments yet, so I was forced to do it as an answer.

Comment: No symbolic links. There are at least two offending directories, which are printed out in the error (replaced with "PATH_HERE" in my question). The offending directories are consistent, and actually empty.